# Why would a Vue3 watcher of a prop not be triggered? (Composition API)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, watch, vue-props

I am desperately trying to `watch` a `prop` in Vue3 (3.2.31, Composition API):

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
import { toRef, watch } from 'vue'

const props = defineProps({
  'trigger-refresh': {
    type: String
  }
})
const triggerRefresh = toRef(props, 'trigger-refresh')
watch(triggerRefresh, (a, b) => console.log('props triggered refresh'))
</script>
```

I trigger the emission of `trigger-refresh`, it is passed to the component with the code above and **I see `triggerRefresh` changing in DevTools→Vue**.

So everything is fine up to the inside of the component except that the **`watch` is not triggered** (i.e. there is no message on the console).

I read the [documentation for Watchers](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html) and responses to a [question about watching props](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59125857/how-to-watch-props-change-with-vue-composition-api-vue-3) (one of the responses is almost identical to what I did) but I simply fail to understand why this does not work in my case.

Comment: what about `watch(()=>triggerRefresh, (a, b) => console.log('props triggered refresh'))`

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim: I tried that too without success (more or less without clearly understanding why, but found out that the first parameter can be a `ref<T>`)

Comment: Try to use camelCase instead of kebab-case like `const props = defineProps({ 'triggerRefresh': { type: String } })`

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim: just tried it - no changes. Please note that the `triggerRefresh` ref extracted from `props` does change correctly (I see that in DevTools)

Comment: As a side note for someone who would be reading this: my intent was to reset the component through an external event. I was passing the prop and intended to reset the component "from inside". I just remembered that this can be done by setting a `key` property on the component (whet it changes, the component is reset). This does not change my question but is good to know.

Comment: @WoJ Then this is XY problem. It won't work as `triggerRefresh` set to true and needs to be unique token in order to trigger a watcher multiple times. Instead, `triggerRefresh` public method should be exposed by the component

Comment: @EstusFlask: sorry but I think I did not understand your comment. Is it related to my question, or the comment about `key` I added?

Comment: try to add `immediate` option `watch(triggerRefresh, (a, b) => console.log('props triggered refresh'),{immediate:true})`

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim: yes! it worked :) Thank you very much. If you would be willing to turn the comment into an answer I would gladly accept it. Thanks again!

Comment: @WoJ To the one with key. It's a hack here (also was with key). A correct way is to expose a method

Comment: @EstusFlask: Is this really a hack? In https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-special-attributes.html#key it is stated that *It can also be used to force replacement of an element/component instead of reusing it.*

Comment: It *can*. But generally shouldn't if you have control over a component in use, it's inefficient and lacks expressiveness. It's acceptable for third-party comps that works the way they work

Comment: @EstusFlask: thanks. I never saw public methods in components but I will look that up. Thanks!

Comment: In composition API this is done with `context.expose`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to add the `immediate` option in order to trigger the watch at the first prop change:

```js
watch(triggerRefresh, (a, b) => console.log('props triggered refresh'), {
  immediate: true
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Prop names are normalized to camel case. As it was stated in the question, it is `triggerRefresh` and not `trigger-refresh` that is seen updated. So it should be:

```
const triggerRefresh = toRef(props, 'triggerRefresh')

watch(triggerRefresh, ...)
```

Or just:

```
watch(() => props.triggerRefresh, ...)
```

Comment: Unfortunately even when changing the name from `trigger-refresh` to `triggerRefresh` the  `watch` is not triggered. And in any case as I mentioned in a comment the `triggerRefresh` ref extracted from `props` **does** change correctly (I see that in DevTools)

Comment: I see. Then it should work. If the problem is that you expected it to be triggered immediately like suggested in comments then that's it, but this isn't something that could be expected from 'refresh' action.