# Calling a child component's method from the parent in Vue composition API?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

In Vue 2 or options API to call a child method from its own parent, we could do it by defining a ref; accessing the ref and calling the method.
something like this:

```
<template>
 <my-component ref="childComponent" />
</template>

<script>
export defult {
 name: 'parentComponent',
 mounted() {
   this.$refs.childComponent.childMethod()
 }
</script>
```

but how we can do that in Vue 3 or composition API?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue3 Parent component call child component method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73725505/vue3-parent-component-call-child-component-method)

Answer (score 1):

We can achieve that in a similar way but with a little difference.
Like options API we define a ref on the template.
Then we access that reference like the following:

```
const childComponent = ref(null)
```

*note that the variable name must be exactly equal to ref value in the template*

Then calling the child method:

```
childComponent.value.childMethod()
```

But if you try it you'll see that childMethod is not accessible. (childMethod is not a function.)

According to the [document](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineexpose)

> "Components using 'script setup' are closed by default".

So, to enable accessing the method from outside of current component, easily expose it using the defineExpose macro in the child component:

```
<script setup>
function childMethod () {
 // I do nothing :P
}

defineExpose({ childMethod })
</script>
```