# In Vue, how can introduce a delay (when watching a prop)?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

In Vue 3 with setup, I have a toast component with a message prop. When the parent passes in an empty message, my toast component needs to hang on to the old message for half a second until an animation completes. How should I do this? I suspect I need a watch on the prop, but vue 3 watch() seems to choke. When I do `watch(props.errorMsg,()=>{})`, I get TS: no overload matches this call.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Execute script after specific delay using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24849/execute-script-after-specific-delay-using-javascript)

Comment: @gre_gor No. Sure I'm going to use setTimeout(), but where do I put it? I think I need a watch or a computed but I don't know which.

Comment: You can't use `watch(props.errorMsg`, it should be `watch(() => props.errorMsg`

Comment: @EstusFlask that's the trick I needed. I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59127059/1585345)

Comment: You haven't shown your code, so that's impossible to answer. Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) function:

```html
<template>
  <transition name="notify">
    <div v-if="show" class="notify_overlay" @click="close">
      <div
        :style="{color: msgColor, backgroundColor: bgColor, borderColor: borderColor, shadow: shadowColor}"
        class="notify_content"
        @click.stop
        @mouseleave="paused = false"
        @mousemove="paused = true"
        @mouseenter="paused = true"
      >
        <div :style="{backgroundColor: progColor}" class="notify_progress">
          <div :style="{width: current + '%', backgroundColor: progInner}" class="notify_progress_inner" />
        </div>
        <div class="notify_header pt-3 px-3">
          <h3 class="notify_title">{{ type }}</h3>
          <button :style="{color: msgColor, borderColor: borderColor}" class="notify_close" type="button" @click="close">
            <div>&#10006;</div>
          </button>
        </div>
        <!-- eslint-disable vue/no-v-html -->
        <div class="notify_text pa-3" v-html="text" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </transition>
</template>

<script>
const colors =
  {
    text:
      {
        error: '#9F3A38',
        success: '#2C662D',
        warning: '#F0AD4E',
        info: '#5BC0DE',
      },
    border:
      {
        error: '#9F3A38',
        success: '#2C662D',
        warning: '#F0AD4E',
        info: '#5BC0DE',
      },
    background:
      {
        error: '#FFF6F6',
        success: '#FCFFF5',
        warning: '#EFE8DE',
        info: '#F5F5FC',
      },
    shadow:
      {
        error: '#FF6C5D',
        success: '#A3C293',
        warning: '#EFCDA5',
        info: '#AAD7DD',
      },
    progress:
      {
        bottom:
          {
            error: '#C62828',
            success: '#388e3c',
            warning: '#ef6c00',
            info: '#1565c0',
          },
        top:
          {
            error: '#ef9a9a',
            success: '#81c784',
            warning: '#ffcc80',
            info: '#64b5f6',
          }
      }
  };

export default
{
  name: 'NotifyBox',
  props:
    {
      modelValue:
      {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
      },
      text:
        {
          type: String,
          default: ''
        },
      type:
        {
          type: String,
          default: 'error',
          validator: (v) => ['error', 'success', 'info', 'warning'].includes(v)
        },
      timeout:
        {
          type: Number,
          default: 1000
        }
    },
  emits: ['update:model-value'],
  data()
  {
    return {
      current: 0,
      paused: false,
    };
  },
  computed:
    {
      show:
      {
        get()
        {
          return this.modelValue;
        },
        set(val)
        {
          this.$emit('update:model-value', val);
        }
      },
      progColor()
      {
        return colors.progress.bottom[this.type];
      },
      progInner()
      {
        return colors.progress.top[this.type];
      },
      msgColor()
      {
        return colors.text[this.type];
      },
      bgColor()
      {
        return colors.background[this.type];
      },
      borderColor()
      {
        return colors.border[this.type];
      },
      shadowColor()
      {
        return '0 0 0 1px ' + colors.shadow[this.type] + ' inset, 0 0 0 0 transparent';
      },
      progStep()
      {
        return 10000 / (6 * this.timeout); // 100%/60 fps * 1000ms/timeout
      }
    },
  watch:
    {
      show:
        {
          immediate: true
          handler: 'start',
        }
    },
  beforeDestroy()
  {
    document.removeEventListener('keydown', this.notifyEscape, false);
  },
  methods:
    {
      close()
      {
        this.show = false;
      },
      notifyEscape(event)
      {
        const e = event || window.event;
        if (!!this.value && e.keyCode === 27)
        {
          this.close();
          // All good browsersвЂ¦
          if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
          // вЂ¦and IE
          if (e.returnValue) e.returnValue = false;
          return false;
        }
      },
      start()
      {
        if (this.show)
        {
          document.addEventListener('keydown', this.notifyEscape, false);
          this.current = 0;
          this.paused = false;
          requestAnimationFrame(this.progress);
        }
        else
        {
          document.removeEventListener('keydown', this.notifyEscape, false);
        }
      },
      progress()
      {
        if (this.show)
        {
          if (this.paused) requestAnimationFrame(this.progress);
          else
          {
            const cur = this.current + this.progStep;
            this.current = cur >= 100 ? 100 : cur;
            if (cur < 100) requestAnimationFrame(this.progress);
            else this.close();
          }
        }
      }
    }
};
</script>

<style>
  .notify_overlay
  {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 257; /* an attempt to be on top of Vuetify dialogs */
    display: flex;
    text-align: initial;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.68);
  }

  .notify_content
  {
    margin: auto;
    background-color: white;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-width: 180px;
  }

  .notify_progress,
  .notify_progress_inner
  {
    height: 10px;
  }

  .notify_header
  {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .notify_title
  {
    flex: 1 1 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0;
  }

  .notify_text
  {
    max-width: 86vw;
    max-height: 86vh;
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
  }

  .notify_text,
  .notify_text pre
  {
    font-family: 'Lucida Console', 'Consolas', monospace;
  }

  .notify_close
  {
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 2px solid;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1;
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    margin: 4px 8px 4px 12px;
    padding: 2px;
  }

  .notify_close div
  {
    transition: transform 0.25s linear;
  }

  .notify_close:hover div
  {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }

  .notify_close:focus
  {
    border-width: 3px;
  }

  .notify_close:active
  {
    transform: translate(1px, 2px);
  }

  .notify-enter-active
  {
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
  }

  .notify-leave-active
  {
    transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(1, 0.5, 0.8, 1);
  }

  .notify-enter,
  .notify-leave-to
  {
    transform: translateX(16px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: I'm very happy to discover this function, but it looks very low level. Do I really need to control the animation frame by frame?

Comment: You don't control the animation - you just use the fact that the browser will try hard to call your callback function about 60 times per second. Once you know that your function will be called 60 times per second - you can calculate how many calls to skip before closing the toast. If you don't like the CSS animation - you can simply remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Watch will do this for you, but you need to supply a callback to specify which property you're watching, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59127059/1585345).

So the working code looks like this...

```
<template>
    <div :class="{'container-error':true, active:active}">
        <div>{{displayErr}}</div>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import { ref, watch } from 'vue'

const props = defineProps < { errorMsg?: string, active: boolean } > ()
let displayErr=ref(props.errorMsg)
watch(()=>props.errorMsg, ()=>{
    if (displayErr.value && displayErr.value !== props.errorMsg) {
        // don't clear the error message until the toast has vanished
        setTimeout(() => { displayErr.value = '' }, 500)
    }
    else if (displayErr.value !== props.errorMsg)
        displayErr.value = props.errorMsg || ''
})
</script>
```